# Using SubProcess with shell=false

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a piece of python that needs to open up a file in OSX, via its default application, that is selected inside Tkinter file open control. I do not know what the file type is when it is selected nor the default app.

```
Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()

child = subprocess.check_call("open" ,filename)
```

My problem is this does not work...if I include shell=True is does but I need to capture the PID of the application that started not the pid of the shell that executed the command.

Any thoughts?

Thanks
C

Answer (score 1):

If the `shell` keyword argument is `False` the input must be a sequence. Also you're passing the `filename` as the second argument, instead of into the first.

```
child = subprocess.check_call(["open", filename])
```

to quote the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I receive a TypeError: bufsize must be an integer when I use that method.

Comment: @ChrisLuff Are you trying to open that file name? then you want `subprocess.check_call(["open", filename])`. All the input should be in that list as the first argument.